# Получить значение ID ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery, link, href

Как получить значение ID ссылки

```
<a class="goto" id="50" href="/karta/categoriya/">Москва</a>


<script>    
$('a.goto').click(function(event) { 
  $.ajax({
    url: "/karta/city/XXXIDXXX"
  })
});
</script>
```

Нужно чтобы при клике на ссылку, в XXXIDXXX вносилось значение ID ссылки. HREF и ID меняется. Class всегда один и тот же.

Пожалуйста если не затруднит, наглядный пример. Очень плохо разбираюсь в этом.

Comment: Атрибут `id` не совсем предназначен для хранения данных. Как вариант, используйте data-атрибуты: `<a data-city="50" ...` и по событию клика `id = $(this).data("city");`

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как сделать чтобы данные из data-city дописывались к URL. В примере с ID (+ this.id) все работает, а с data-city не пойму, что нужно вставить

Comment: то же самое: `url: "/karta/city/" + $(this).data("city")`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает.

Comment: можете полный исходник закинуть

Comment: у меня точно такая проблема с данными

Comment: user201503, исходник чего? Выше в теме полный код по моему вопросу. А Sergiks дал подробный ответ в своем комментарии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>    
$('a.goto').click(function(event) { 
  $.ajax({
    url: "/karta/city/" + this.id
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!! Все работает. 2 часа ломал голову:-)